# CSS is not applied in dev org

Tags: visualforce, css

I have two orgs, dev and sandbox.
I've written a VF page using VF components like pageblock and applied my own CSS to them.
The problem is that in my dev org the new style is not applied while in the sandbox it does.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: hardcoded url ?

Comment: static resource

Comment: Can you post a small snippet of your VF page? Are you using URLFOR?

Comment: Are your styles applied by element ID or by class?

Comment: applied by class

Answer (score 2):

How are you storing the CSS? if you have stored as a static resource remember to copy that static resource from your sandbox to your dev box. If it is inline or it is in static resources but not working try using firebug or similar to debug in browser.

Comment: static resource; I made sure its the same in both orgs

Comment: Also check that the static resource content type is "text/css" in both orgs.